# Which bicycle headlights should I review?

Tags: discussion, blog

After the very successful [bike tail light review](http://bicycles.blogoverflow.com/2012/03/tail-light-review/) I conducted last winter, I decided that it's time to look at front lights. This winter, I'll be contacting light manufacturers about getting review samples, and will possibly purchase some lights myself as well (since I need some new ones anyways!).

I'd like your help deciding which lights to review. **Please [fill out this short survey](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/viewform?formkey=dDhUX0FkeER3cXdrajIzaG9mcVBzdUE6MQ)** to help me figure out what lights are commonly used, and which ones people want to know more about.

A full review, with pictures and commentary, will be posted on this site's blog... eventually. Last year it took me three months, so don't hold your breath, but do feel free to leave suggestions!

Comment: Bontrager Ion 2 and Ion 1 headlights.

Comment: Hi @Zeus. Thanks for the suggestion - could you please fill out the survey form and suggest them there?

Comment: http://www.dutchbikebits.com/index.php?route=product/category&path=40 has a list of good bike lights some of them may be less known in the USA

Comment: I hope you still accept suggestions as I just submitted one.

Comment: @Informaficker thanks! I'll go check out your suggestion.

Comment: link to the review please?

Comment: @rogerdpack I've since actually created a whole website devoted to bike light information: http://www.bikelightdatabase.com.

Comment: @nhinkle oh I see this was a tail light review, for some reason I thought it was a head mounted light review, which I couldn't find on the site [?].  Sorry for the noise.

Comment: @rogerdpack the original review I did on the bikes.SE blog was a taillights review, then I followed up with another taillights review and a headlights review the next year. Those are all [here](http://bicycles.blogoverflow.com/category/lights-2/). On my new site, all recent reviews are posted [here](http://www.bikelightdatabase.com/reviews/), both front and read lights. From the [headlight database](http://www.bikelightdatabase.com/headlights/) and [taillight database](http://www.bikelightdatabase.com/taillights/) you can filter by "has review" to see all reviewed lights (indicated w/ a star).

Comment: If you're specifically looking for helmet mounted lights (if that's what you meant by head mounted?) then you can also filter the mounts on the headlight database by only selecting the "helmet" checkbox for that option.